# How to run two instances of MySQL for replication

Tags: mysql

I want to use replication of database in same machine. So I need to create two instance of mysql. It will be helpful if any one describe that how to get the server id.

Comment: whats your platform/o.s ?

Comment: http://www.pythian.com/blog/using-mysqld_multi-to-manage-multiple-servers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create separate data and log directories

We need to create new directories for our datadir and log folder (if used). Also we need to assign proper permissions on those folders:

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql2
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql2/
mkdir /var/log/mysql2
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql2
```

2. Create a new mysql configuration file

Next we need a separate configuration file. We can start by copying the existing one and changing the needed values. This example was taken on a debian machine that holds the mysql configurations under /etc/mysql/my.cnf. We just copy this folder and modify it from there:

```
cp -R /etc/mysql/ /etc/mysql2
```

2. Create a new mysql configuration file

Next we need a separate configuration file. We can start by copying the existing one and changing the needed values. This example was taken on a debian machine that holds the mysql configurations under /etc/mysql/my.cnf. We just copy this folder and modify it from there:

if you use a redhat variant package then your configuration file is under

`/etc/my.cnf by default and you can just copy it directly:`

Next, we need to edit our new configuration file and at least update the mysql port (default to 3306), the pid and socket to be different than the default ones, and also point the data and log folders to the ones created before. On my debian machine this can be done with something like this:

```
cd /etc/mysql2/
sed -i 's/3306/3307/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/mysqld.sock/mysqld2.sock/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/mysqld.pid/mysqld2.pid/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/var\/lib\/mysql/var\/lib\/mysql2/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/var\/log\/mysql/var\/log\/mysql2/g' my.cnf
```

3. Initializing and starting

Finally we need to initialize the default dbs:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2/
```